# Repository contains code with original commit message, despite the log showing a commit in which that code was removed?

Tags: git

With two repositories A and B:

- A has a master branch that is often committed to origin
- B will often merge changes from A

A typical workflow for repository A is to checkout a branch, merge that branch back into master and then push the master to origin.

A typical workflow for repository B is to checkout a branch, merge A.master into that branch, and then push that branch to Bs origin.

Then B.branch is merged into A. For a while now I have had the feeling that I've been making changes on repository A more than once. Things I have thought that I noticed:

- Files that I deleted previously seem to reappear
- Code that I have added to A.master seems to get deleted

But it's also clear to me that repository B HAS been merging A.master, since new code does appear.

On trying to follow up with this, I found on repository B that there IS a commit where some code was deleted. But that code seems to 'reappear', and there is no commit where that is recorded - `git blame` shows the original commit message.

How is this possible? That code shows the original commit message, despite incorporating a merge in which that code was deleted?

Comment: What is B's origin? How do the changes you make in B get merged back into A's master branch?

Comment: B is a fork of A. I merge branches from B into A branches. Then merge A branches to A master, then push to origin master. Then B pulls from A master

Comment: I think I need recommendations for books on Git

Comment: I know that git is distributed and all, but it sounds like you've got some confusion about where your source of truth is. If B is a fork of A, then B's master should be pulling commits directly from A's master, then B branches should branch of B's master. By branching off B's master then merging in A's master, you are creating a confusing history that could easily trick the auto-merge into re-creating deleted files, etc. It's doable.... it's just extra complicated and requires going over your merge commits with a fine-tooth comb.

Comment: Unfortunately (or fortunately?) book recommendations are out of scope for Stack Overflow, but git's documentation is a really good starting place: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: See especially the section on workflows: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All commits are snapshots.

If you find that some file exists in some snapshot, all you know is that the file exists in the snapshot.  You must then look at its previous snapshot—its *parent* commit—if it is a regular commit, or *all* of its previous snapshots, plural, if it is a merge commit.  In other words, you must now check all of its immediate parents.  If that same file exists in the parents, in the same form, it is obviously the same file with the same contents.  If it exists in the parents in *different* forms, it was modified during the merge.  If it exists in one parent in the same or different form, and is entirely absent in the other parent, it was carried through by someone, and perhaps changed as well.  If it does not exist in its previous parent(s), it was newly created in this commit, and so on.

Repeat, for every commit and all of its parents, and you have the history of this particular file starting at this particular commit and working backwards.  And that's what `git log` and `git blame` do, except that they—necessarily in many cases—*cheat* at merges.  A merge has multiple parents: which parent(s) should Git follow?  If you're attempting to assemble a linear view of events that are inherently nonlinear, you simply *discard* some parent(s) while doing this backwards, commit-and-its-parent(s), one-pair-at-a-time walk through history.

Of course, discarding a parent also prevents you from viewing what happened in *that* particular line of work.  So that answers this question:

> How is this possible? That code shows the original commit message, despite incorporating a merge in which that code was deleted?

Some commit introduces the file:

```
...--o--o--+--+--+--...
```

(`+` commits have the file).

Some later commit *removes* the file, but there's a child of one of these commits that has the file, before the removal:

```
...--o--o--+--+--+--o--o--...
               \
                +--+--...
```

Now at some point, you or someone else use `git merge` to combine these lines of work:

```
...--o--o--+--+--+--o--o--o--?--...
               \            /
                +--+--...--+--...
```

This merge commit, whose contents are `?` here, has *two* parents, one of which has the file (working along the bottom row) and one of which does not (working along the top row).  If the merge was done "correctly", according to your correctness criteria, the file should—I believe—be gone in `?`, so let's draw that:

```
...--o--o--+--+--+--o--o--o--o--...
               \            /
                +--+--...--+--...
```

Later, someone else *re-merges*:

```
                              ours
                                v
...--o--o--+--+--+--o--o--o--o--o--?--...
               \            /     /
                +--+--...--+--+--+--...
                           ^     ^
                         base  theirs
```

Now, during *this* merge, the merge base will be the commit marked `base`, the `--ours` commit is the one so marked, and the `--theirs` commit is the one so marked.  Git will see that, in our line of work, we removed the file and they either changed it, or didn't.  If they didn't change it, Git's automatic answer to "what should be in `?`" includes *keep the file removed*.  If not—if they changed the file between `base` and `theirs`—Git's automatic answer is: *Help!  I give up!  Mr Programmer, you'll have to decide the result for yourself.*

If whoever does this merge decides "keep the changed file", it's now *back*.  If they decide "keep the file discarded", it's now *gone*.  So that's the new merge result that goes in `?`.

Every new merge results in this same issue: they *have* the file, we *don't*, the merge base does, and they may or may not have modified it.  Should someone decide, at any point, to keep *their* version of the file, now the file is back:

```
...--o--o--+--+--+--o--o--o--o--o--o--...--+--+
               \            /     /       /
                +--+--...--+--+--+--...--+--+
```

If you're the one doing the merges, then every time *they* change the file, you must decide: *For the correct result, should I keep the file?*

Using `git log` *can* help you find out if someone made the wrong decision at some point, but in general you will need `--full-history` to force `git log` to run down *both* paths.  That is, at each merge commit, Git has to start going down both sides of the merge, comparing each commit to its parent, pairwise, one pair at a time.

Without more details regarding who's merging which commits and how, it's difficult to say anything more.  Just be aware that the tools Git provides for tracing files will always have issues at the points where lines diverge and re-converge.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I will see if I can reproduce it using branches on a single repository

Comment: This is such a good answer. I love Git. But sometimes hate it... This scenario that you have described - is that possible for a particular line in a file as well? I would assume it is...

Comment: @ZachSmith: sure—but note that `git blame`, for instance, tells you which commit touched a line that you are viewing that *is* in (the snapshot in) whichever commit you start from. If you're looking for a line that has disappeared, and it's not in the file, `git blame` isn't showing you anything in the first place.

Comment: Ah. thank you. So if a line of code was removed in subsequent commits, then I would not see that in the commit overview that GitHub provides via `git blame`